# Нет доступа в Одноклассники с блока "Поделиться"

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Я разрабатываю сайт. Доменное имя сайта knitting-master.ru. Поставил блок "Поделиться" от Яндекса. Вариант блока который со счетчиками. Ко всем соц. сетям есть доступ кроме одноклассников. При нажатии на Одноклассники выходит окно с надписями - Нет доступа к ресурсу. Попробуйте позже. Пробовал позже, ничего не меняется. У моего знакомого который поставил себе на сайт этот же блок недели на 3 раньше все работает. Обращался в службу поддержки Одноклассников, там сказали что причина не с их стороны, а скорее всего со стороны разработчика кнопок. Потом я им сказал, что видел в инете статьи про то, что Одноклассники иногда не дают доступ по причине каких то нарушений. Например сайт может содержать материалы для взрослых. У меня таких материалов никогда не было, сайт о вязаных вещах, но возможно есть какие то другие нарушения. После этого с их стороны наступила пауза. Я так думаю они наверное стали проверять возможные нарушения. После чего последовал ответ что никаких нарушений на моем сайте нет. И поэтому это не по их причине доступа нет. Нужно обратиться к разработчикам блока "Поделиться", то есть к Яндексу. Помогите пожалуйста решить данную проблему!!!

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы мы обратились к Яндексу или поговорили с Одноклассниками?

Comment: Ну с одноклассниками я уже говорил. Я думаю лучше к Яндексу наверное. А вы это кто? Я же сюда с Яндекса перешел. Я идумал, что вы это и есть Яндекс.

Comment: Мы не Яндекс :-) Мы вот кто https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour